# Center of a subgroup of a certain $2$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $2$-group of class 2 (that is $G^{\prime}\leq Z(G)$) and $Z(G)$ be cyclic. 
We could verify that $G^{\prime}=\langle [a,b]\rangle$ for some $a, b \in G$. 
If $H=\langle a,b\rangle$, then by a well-known argument we have $G=HC_G(H)$  and $G^{\prime}=H^{\prime}$. 
Let $|G^{\prime}|=|H^{\prime}|=2^n$ for some integer $n>0$. Thus we have ${\rm exp}(\frac{G}{Z(G)})={\rm exp}(\frac{H}{Z(H)})=2^n$.

How could we show that $Z(H)=\langle a^{2^n}, b^{2^n}, [a,b]\rangle$? 
 (Since ${\rm exp}(\frac{H}{Z(H)})=2^n$ and $G=HC_G(H)$, 
 $\langle a^{2^n}, b^{2^n}, [a,b]\rangle\leq Z(H)\leq Z(G)$. In particular $Z(H)$ is cyclic.
  I could not show the converse of the first inclusion)

Any answer will be greatly appreciated!

Notations: By $C_G(H)$ I mean $C_G(H):=\{g\in G | gh=hg, \forall  h\in H\}$ 
 and ${\rm exp}(G)$ denotes the exponent of the group $G$.

Comment: We must have $H/Z(H) \cong \langle aZ(H) \rangle \times \langle bZ(H) \rangle \cong C_{2^n} \times C_{2^n}$, and the property you want to prove follows from that.

Comment: Dear professor Derek Holt thank you very much for your exact answer!